# Passing script as user data into AWS EC2 spot instance

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to create a new spot request using aws cli but it gives me an error if i pass a shell script as user-data to spot request

i tried this

```
    aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price "0.04" --instance-count 1 --launch-specification "{\"UserData\": \"/srv/user-data.sh\",\"InstanceType\": \"m1.small\"}"
```

and this gives me an error

```
    Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data (400 response code)
```

and

how can i Tags my spot request with Name & Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly that, aws expects a base64 encoded string to be passed for the UserData value.  Why the tools doesn't do this for you, I don't know.

So, instead of the string:

```
  /srv/user-data.sh
```

Use a base64 encoded version of the string (using an online encoder, I got the following):

```
 L3Nydi91c2VyLWRhdGEuc2g=
```

I'm guessing the final json it should look something like this:

```
   '{"UserData": "L3Nydi91c2VyLWRhdGEuc2g=","InstanceType": "m1.small"}'
```

Creating tags is pretty straight forward.  Here's a link to the 'aws' CLI command documentation:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

You'll need to determine the resource AMI id:

```
  aws ec2 create-tags --resources ami-78a54011 --tags Key=Name,Value=myname
```

Comment: test="$(cat /srv/user-data.sh| base64)"
aws ec2 request-spot-instances --spot-price "0.04" --instance-count 1 --launch-specification "{\"UserData\": \"$test\",\"InstanceType\": \"m1.small\"}"
but it gives me an error
Error parsing parameter '--launch-specification': Invalid JSON: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 133 (char 133

Comment: @user310685 getting better, now you just need to figure why the json is invalid.  Echo out the created string

Comment: Error parsing parameter '--launch-specification': Invalid JSON: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 133 (char 133)
JSON received: {"UserData": "IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKZWNobyAiaGkgaXQgd29ya3MgbW9zZXMiID4gL3Nydi9tb3Nlc25ld2luc3Rh
bmNlc3VzZXItZGF0YXdvcmtzLnR4dAo=","InstanceType": "m1.small"}

Comment: @user310685 Looks like perfect json to me.  Try hardcodeing that string above.

Comment: hardcoding it works.. but cant i take it into a variable as pass it

Comment: @user310685 Try with single quotes instead of having to use the escaped `"` just to factor out one degree of futz.  Also, see my update about your tagging question.  I'd recommend not asking 2 seperate things in one post

Comment: single quotes does not work it repeats the same error Error parsing parameter '--launch-specification': Invalid JSON

Comment: @user310685  If the hardcoded string works with the base64 encoded strgin, but not the  '$test' substitution, it sounds like a shell substitution issue.  This solution takes care of your initial question about the encoding problem you're having.  I'd suggest creating another question specifically with your shell command to get some attention from someone who's more shell script expert (I'm more an AWS resource)

Answer (score 1):

yes i got it to work like this

```
     test="$(cat /srv/user-data.sh | base64 -w 0)"

     aws ec2 request-spot-instances \"UserData\": \"$test\",\"InstanceType\": \"m1.small\"}"
```

the problem mainly solved with

```
   -w, --wrap=COLS
          wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76).  Use 0 to disable line wrapping
```

and for tagging the aws instances

```
  aws ec2 create-tags --resources $instanceId --tags Key=Name,Value=$instancesName
```